# Apple push notifications on GCM

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create application for Android and iOS and, i want to use push notification on both the application. I'm going to have a server app that will be sending the notification.

but i am trying to APNS and Parse SDK it's common to use ,but i want GCM through push notifications on iOS ,can you please how can it possible ,any such information about GCM to iOS push notifications ,i am googling but i want some suggestions for GCM through iOS device notifications.Can you help me.thank you.

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "GCM to iOS push notifications" and "GCM through iOS device notifications" means.

Comment: In android i have used GCM for push notifications ,but in iOS also it is possible?and can you explain how it's possible?

Comment: GCM is for Android devices only, APNS is for iOS devices only. If you want to have one push notification service for both types of devices, you should use some third party service, for example Parse Push Notification. You can use Parse Push Notification to [target by platform](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-platform/REST).

Answer (score 1):

Update: GCM now supports IOS. See Grigo´s comment.

GCM is Android specific. If you want to avoid dealing with 2 different services for IOS and Android, you can use something like Amazon SNS for example. SNS now supports pushing cloud notifications to Android, IOS and Windows devices via the AWS Mobile SDK.

Comment: GCM can be used for iOS too
Link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Answer (score 1):

There is very good descriptive instructions in [Google Cloud Messaging for iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start)  guide. It shows whole flow from registration of device token to receive push from server with code example.

After go through above guide, you may go for [Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#set_up_your_cocoapods_dependencies) and you are almost done to use GCM with iOS application